# How to preserve UIImageView's width:height ratio when changing width or height

Tags: ios, uiimageview

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to preserve the ration of width:height when one of those two changes.

If you set the image of the UIImageView, the frame gets set accordingly. Say the image is 10x10, so the imageView has a 10x10 frame. If you now shrink the width of the imageView to be 5 wide, the image can appropriately scale to be 5x5, however, the imageView becomes a 5x10 imageView, adding transparent blocks above and below the image.

Currently I've set a height constraint that mimics the ratio of the image I want to set, however, if the image is ever updated or changed to one with a different ratio, it will mess up how the image is displayed.

Is there a generic way to tell the imageView to automatically scale it's width and height to be the same original ratio of the image, or is there any property on UIImageView to allow it to preserve it's width:height ratio when changing only one of the properties?

Comment: try image.clipToBound = true

Answer (score 0):

1. Use aspect ratio Autolayout constraint.
2. Set Mode to Aspect Fill.
3. Check Clip subviews.

[image: Screenshot]